# How to allow a specific "unknown source"

Tags: unknown-sources

I would like to be able to install applications from a specific "unknown source" (it's our company continuous integration server).  Is there a way to do that?  (Using a Samsung Galaxy 7 if it matters).

Comment: No... Unknown Sources is all or nothing, you allow everything outside of Google Play, or nothing. Best to enable it, install your app, then disable it.

Comment: @acejavelin Mostly yes, but not exactly. Make the "installer" a system app, and it would be able to install even with "unknown sources" unchecked. Example: Make the *F-Droid* app an system app, and you could use F-Droid as "trusted source".

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.  As [acejavelin](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/146132/acejavelin) says, "Unknown Sources is all or nothing, you allow everything outside of Google Play, or nothing."

Depending on your phone, you may be prompted to allow for just this install (for example, Samsung Galaxy 7), or you may have to enable, install, disable (for example, Sony Xperia Z1).  The former is obviously safer.